# Removing elements in a List withing a range

Tags: java, list

This method is supposed to accept a list, a element, a min value(inclusive), and a max value(exclusive). It then removes all elements within the range with the same element.

For example, for the list (0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16), a call of removeInRange(list, 0, 5, 13) should produce the list (0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16).

I am having trouble with near the end of the list in which it removes too much. Any suggestions?

```
private static void removeInRange(List<Integer> thing, int element,
            int firstInclusive, int secondExclusive) {

    int i = firstInclusive;

    while ( i >= firstInclusive && i < secondExclusive && i < thing.size()) {
        if (thing.get(i)== element) {
            thing.remove(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to use an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex).removeAll(Arrays.asList(element));
```