# Remove In Range in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following requirements to write a java method.
Write a method called `removeInRange` that accepts four parameters: a List of integers, an element value, a starting index, and an ending index. The method's behavior is to remove all occurrences of the given element that appear in the list between the starting index (inclusive) and the ending index (exclusive). Other values and occurrences of the given value that appear outside the given index range are not affected.

For example, for the list (0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16), a call of removeInRange(list, 0, 5, 13) should produce the list (0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16). Notice that the zeros located at indices between 5 inclusive and 13 exclusive in the original list (before any modifications were made) have been removed.
I have written the method as follows:

```
public static void removeInRange(List<Integer> list,int value,int beg,int end)
{
    beg=new Integer(beg);
    //Integer b=beg;
    int count=0;
    list.subList(5, 13);
/*  for( Integer b:list.subList(beg, end))

    {
        if(list.get(b)==value)
        list.remove(b);
    }
    */
    Iterator<Integer> iter = list.subList(beg, end).iterator();
    int i=iter.next();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        if (iter.next().intValue()==value) 
        {
            iter.remove();

        }

    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

However, this method gives me the error Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`.I want any hints or suggestions how I can change my method to avoid this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330174/removing-elements-in-a-list-withing-a-range?rq=1

Comment: For `ArrayList`, you do not need to use an iterator; you can use the `ArrayList.get(index)` function. The complete solution to your problem is present at the following link. Use that program to rectify your program. [Complete working program](http://www.sr2jr.com/textbook-solutions/computer-science/71101009/building-java-programs-a-back-to-basics-approach-arraylists).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using a `List` type that doesn't support `remove()`:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16});
removeInRange(list, 0, 5, 13);
```

will give you the exception, but:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10, 0, 12, 0, 14, 0, 16}));
removeInRange(list, 0, 5, 13);
```

will not.

This is because `Arrays.asList()` returns an implementation of `List` that doesn't support the `remove()` operation, and throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead, whereas `java.util.ArrayList` supports it.

You have two solutions to this problem:

- return a new `List` which is a copy of the list passed in parameter, minus what you want to remove: `public static List<Integer> removeInRange(List<Integer> list,int value,int beg,int end)`
- throws an `UnsupportedOperationException` when the list given as parameter doesn't support `remove()`, and let the caller see what to do.

Answer (score 0):

One fix is to create a new type of list that does support removal such as LinkedList, copy the elements from list to the LinkedList, perform the operation and then return the LinkedList.

Answer (score 0):

You might use something like the snippet below .. remember that you are changing the very list you are iterating over ... so use the right things to control how many times you need to check for removal of an integer value.

```
public static void removeInRange(List<Integer> list, int value, int beg,int end)
{
    int n = end - beg;
    int i = beg;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (list.get(i) == value) {
            list.remove(i);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this logic throw ConcurrentModificationException since you are modifying and removing from list at the same time?

Comment: Only removing items. List does change, but we computed how many checks before starting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?:

```
public void removeInRange(List<Integer> list, int element, int startInd, int endInd) {
    for (int i = endInd - 1; i >= startInd; i--) {
        if (list.get(i) == element) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removeInRange(List<Integer> list, int value, int beg,int end)
{
    for (int i = beg; i < end; i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == value) {
            list.remove(i);
            i--;
            end--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.